# Python behave userdata parsing in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-behave

Hi there I would like to ask for help with this problem.

Currently I'm trying pass to user data triggeredBy from teamcity.

-D triggeredBy="Test Name"

but this pass to context.config.userdata only '"Test'

is there any way how to fix this?

Can I somehow use custom userdata parser?

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Please describe your environment and how you invoke Behave.

Comment: @Lenormju thank you for your reaction, I will prepare minimal reproducer to show what I mean.

Comment: Here is minimal reproducer https://github.com/JirakJ/stackoverflow-minimal-reproducer

Comment: I find out that from terminal it works well but problem come when I use args in pycharm. There come to play some escaping in arguments and than are parameters badly parsed. We can mark this issue as resolved.

Comment: I'm glad you found the cause of the problem. There are subtle differences between regular terminal and Pycharm invocation.